# Formatting the print statement for multiple numpy arrays inside a dictionary Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, printing

I am trying to modify my print statement within the for loop below so that it iterates through the list and the dictionary and prints the values of the first and second numpy arrays. In accordance to the `Timeframes` list. How can I modify the print statement below to get the Expected output below?

```
import numpy as np

Timeframes = ['Entirety:', 'Last Month:', 'Three Months:', 'Six Months:', 'Last Year:', 'Last Two Years:']
values = {[np.array([777.2062628 ,97.44704834 , 77.2062628 , 73.2062628 , 65.28 ,
       88.22628]), np.array([31040.02425794,   115.31287155,   115.31287155,   232.78473351,
         437.44961679,  4152.56739805])]}

for timeframe, values[0] in zip(Timeframes, iterator):
    print(f'{timeframe:<23} ${round(iterator[0][recordcounter],2):<15}${round(iterator[1][recordcounter],2):<14}')
```

Expected Output:

```
Entirety:               $777.2062628      $31040.02425794     
Last Month:             $97.44704834      $115.31287155          
Three Months:           $77.2062628       $115.31287155          
Six Months:             $73.2062628       $232.78473351         
Last Year:              $65.28            $437.44961679         
Last Two Years:         $88.22628         $4152.56739805
```

Comment: What is your question about it?

Comment: Sorry it was incomplete. I edited the question back

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: Go back to doing something simpler.  For example do a simple iteration.  `for i in [1,2,3]: print(i)`, and then do something with a zip and so on.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it gives me an error and I cannot get to the expected value

Comment: Show the error!  Your goal should be understanding, not just the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make timeframes a numpy object with the same depth, you can stack the arrays together (or simply input them togeather).

In this case, let's use vstack and transpose.

First we stack the arrays together:

```py
import numpy as np

Timeframes = np.array([['Entirety:', 'Last Month:', 'Three Months:', 'Six Months:', 'Last Year:', 'Last Two Years:']])
values = np.array([[777.2062628 ,97.44704834 , 77.2062628 , 73.2062628 , 65.28 ,
       88.22628], [31040.02425794,   115.31287155,   115.31287155,   232.78473351,
         437.44961679,  4152.56739805]])

data=np.vstack((Timeframes,values))
```

data is now:

```py
[['Entirety:' 'Last Month:' 'Three Months:' 'Six Months:' 'Last Year:'
  'Last Two Years:']
 ['777.2062628' '97.44704834' '77.2062628' '73.2062628' '65.28'
  '88.22628']
 ['31040.02425794' '115.31287155' '115.31287155' '232.78473351'
  '437.44961679' '4152.56739805']]
```

data.T is then:

```
[['Entirety:' '777.2062628' '31040.02425794']
 ['Last Month:' '97.44704834' '115.31287155']
 ['Three Months:' '77.2062628' '115.31287155']
 ['Six Months:' '73.2062628' '232.78473351']
 ['Last Year:' '65.28' '437.44961679']
 ['Last Two Years:' '88.22628' '4152.56739805']]
```

Finally we can do a simple loop on the transposed data:

```py
for line in data.T:
    print(line[0],line[1],line[2])
```

This gives us:

```
Entirety: 777.2062628 31040.02425794
Last Month: 97.44704834 115.31287155
Three Months: 77.2062628 115.31287155
Six Months: 73.2062628 232.78473351
Last Year: 65.28 437.44961679
Last Two Years: 88.22628 4152.56739805
```

Note you can format out the output further by using a simple helper function:

```
def format_as_money(num):
    return '$'+str(round(float(num),2))
```

Then you can edit your print statement line:

```py
for line in data.T:
    print(line[0],format_as_money(line[1]),format_as_money(line[2]))
```

Which gives:

```
Entirety: $777.21 $31040.02
Last Month: $97.45 $115.31
Three Months: $77.21 $115.31
Six Months: $73.21 $232.78
Last Year: $65.28 $437.45
Last Two Years: $88.23 $4152.57
```